# Install private maven package within Github Action

Tags: java, maven, gradle, continuous-integration, github-actions

I've created java-library for sharing between different company's applications.
Then I configured building and publishing the library as a Maven-package into Gihub's maven private registry.
The package has been successfully built and published.

Then I added the repo to my application's gradle:

```
...
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/<my-organization>/backend-library")
        credentials {
            username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("USERNAME")
            password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
        }
    }
}
...
```

I defined username and token. When I'm building the application on my local machine, everything is OK: package has downloaded and application successfully built.

The problem occurs when I try to push changes and build them using Github action.
I configured following workflow:

```yaml
...
  job:
    env:
      USERNAME: Username
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.WORK_DIR }}

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.WORK_DIR }}

      - name: List files in the repository
        run: ls -la

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 17

      - name: Analyze code
        run: ./gradlew check

      - name: Run Unit-tests
        run: ./gradlew test
...
```

But now I'm getting error:

```
> Task :plugins:mapping:check UP-TO-DATE

> Task :plugins:register-invite:compileJava FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':plugins:register-invite:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':plugins:register-invite:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find <my_org_name>:backend-library:1.6.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/<my_org_name>/backend-library/1.6.1/backend-library-1.6.1.pom
       - https://maven.pkg.github.com/<my_org_name>/backend-library/com/<my_org_name>/backend-library/1.6.1/backend-library-1.6.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :plugins:register-invite

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
```

But the library exists in this location, I've already installed it locally!

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I see the the pom file in the searched locations. Have you manually verified that the JAR files are in that same folder in your Maven repo? Most likely: a) the account does not have permissions to read those files from Maven, b) the files were not published where you expected them, c) not all of the files you expected to be published were actually published.

Comment: Thank you for ideas.
All files are published to Github's private Maven registry.
I think everything published as expected, because I tried to install module on two local machines and it was successful. 
The difference is that I'm installing module on my machine using my Github token, but in CI we're using GITHUB_TOKEN. According to documentation it should have all needed permissions.

Comment: @GreenSaguaro The list of files on Github's Maven:
Assets

backend-library-1.6.1.module.sha512
backend-library-1.6.1.module.sha256
backend-library-1.6.1.module.md5
backend-library-1.6.1.module.sha1
backend-library-1.6.1.module
backend-library-1.6.1.pom.sha512
backend-library-1.6.1.pom.sha256
backend-library-1.6.1.pom.md5
backend-library-1.6.1.pom.sha1
backend-library-1.6.1.pom
backend-library-1.6.1.jar.sha512
backend-library-1.6.1.jar.sha256
backend-library-1.6.1.jar.md5
backend-library-1.6.1.jar.sha1
backend-library-1.6.1.jar

Comment: Can you show more of your Gradle file? Specifically how you are declaring the dependency? Also, what is the Maven group name of your `backend-library`?